# how to check uploaded file size smaller than or equals to 20 kb limit?

Tags: php, file-upload

Our application has a requirement that all the uploaded files should be below or equals to 20 KB limit. I am unable to calculate the filesize in PHP as I don't know how it calculates filesize for each 1KB.

I am thinking that 1 KB equals to 1024 bytes so 20 KB is equals to 20*1024 = 20480. Is this correct? My code is accepting files larger than 20KB.

```
function my_method_name() { 

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit-button-name'] ) && !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
        if($_FILES['file_name']['size'] == 0) {                               
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            $path = /Path/to/dir;
             $allowed =  array('gif','GIF','png','PNG','jpg','JPG','JPEG','jpeg');
            $filename = $_FILES['file_name']['name'];
            $filesize = $_FILES['file_name']['size'];
            $ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) && $filesize > 20480) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                $id = media_handle_upload('file_name', 1199); //post id of Client Files page
                return $id; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: You should probably replace your `1` / `0` values with `true` / `false`. It shows your intent much more clearly.

Comment: Also… what are you `return`ing from? Is this code snippet inside another function? What is `do_upload`? Should that be `do_upload()`?

Comment: @Chris, I din't get you. that's ok, but I want know how to compare the file size =< 20KB

Comment: @Chris, I have edited my above question. plz check it.

Comment: Prasad, I have already provided an answer to your question below. Before I review your new code, please check my answer and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition for returning `0` is

```
!in_array($ext,$allowed) && $filesize > 20480
```

In order for it to be true, *both* conditions must be true. That is, only files with a size greater than 20480 *and* with an extension that isn't allowed will cause the first branch to be followed.

Switch `&&` to `||`.

Alternatively, it is usually clearer to put the "positive" path first in `if` / `else` blocks. You could do

```
if (in_array($ext, $allowed) && $filesize <= (20 * 1024)) {
    // Logic to handle accepted download
} else {
    // Logic to handle rejected download
}
```

Comment: I read that as OP wanting to check if it's an allowed file *and* it's under the limit, hence removing the `!`?

Comment: @LeonardChallis, as I commented on the question, the OP's intent isn't entirely clear. I suggested replacing integer return values with Boolean ones to help with that. But now the question has been changed to return an `$id` value, which changes the semantics. Still, I think the first branch in the question is the "not permitted" branch, which should be triggered if the file extension isn't permitted or of the file is too big. (But if you're right, OP would have to flip the comparison operator as well as getting rid of `!`).

Comment: @Chris, Worked like a charm. Its a small if condition problem, so I replace && with || . So I guess my calculation for 20 KB is correct, for every 1KB php calculates as 1 KB * 1024 bytes = 20480 bytes(20 KB) , is that right? Thanks Bro.

Comment: @prasadchinthala, it depends on your exact definition of what a kilobyte is. Some developers would say that  what you have now is technically 20 [_kibibytes_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte). The "ibi" prefixes are for base 2 numbers (× 1024), whereas standard prefixes like "kilo" generally mean base 10 numbers (× 1000). You can thank the hard drive industry for that; they switched to a base-10 definition so they could print bigger numbers on the box. In either case, I'd write out the multiplication (like in the second part of my answer), not the total. IMO it's clearer that way.